# Understanding the Application of HMM to a Dataset

Tags: r, hidden-markov-model

I have been working on a dataset that has $1000$ rows and $10$ columns with $1$ response and $9$ predictor variables. The response variable is binary and the predictors are integers.

I am thinking to apply hidden Markov model to predict response variable $y$ for given predictors $x_i$, $i=1,...,9$. I have read many documents and forum discussions about how to apply hidden Markov models for prediction purposes. However, I could not clarify/resolve my questions/concerns.

Let me tell you what I know about how to apply HMM into my problem, for sure; since $y$ is binary, I have $2$ hidden states; "$0$" and "$1$".

What I am not sure is as follows:

- How should we handle observations? That is; (1) history of $y$ itself could be observations, just like a time series model, (2) one of the predictors could be observations (not sure how to select the one), or (3) all $9$ predictors could be observations. However, when I read the functions of HMM in $R$, observations always defined as *sequence of observations*, then how to apply the third option? Can sequence of observations be a matrix? Are all these options always available (even might not be options)? How to know which one to choose?
- If I choose to apply the first option given above, then are observable states (observations) as the same as the hidden states?
- If I choose to apply the third option given above, how to create emission probabilities for each predictor/observation?
- I will be using $R$ to solve the problem. Which function would be more suitable for my problem. Because, I have tried the third option with *depmixS4* package, but I got "NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 10)" error.

Thank you.

Comment: Are your predictors discrete or continuous? You might want to make them discrete by binning them into finitely many categories. Usually, your emission probabilities estimators would come from maximizing the likelihood for a particular distribution. For instance, a simple way would be to use proportions. You also might want to look into Baum-Welch algo. You supply it an initial HMM guess, and it uses EM techniques to converge your matrices.

Comment: My predictors are discrete. Would you take a look to another post about the same dataset here: http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210668/hidden-states-that-have-never-observed-in-the-dataset